# What stops sprinkler heads from retracting?

Tags: sprinkler-system

I have a reticulation system in my lawn. Recently I replaced some of the sprinkler heads. But they don't always retract; ie when the water pressure is reduced or off they stick up above the lawn.

The head is brand new and has been in for around a month and doesn't retract. They look like this:
[image: sprinkler]

Is this because I got cheap sprinklers or does it means there is dirt in the system?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These type of sprinkler heads typically have a spring inside of them that pulls the head back down when there is no water pressure to be pushing them up. When they don't pull down, there is either something jamming the head, like dirt getting in there, or the spring just isn't pulling hard enough.

Since these are new heads, there is a chance they might just be cheap and don't have great springs in them. You can try to unscrew the sprinkler at the part that is in the middle of your picture. When you do this you should be able to see the spring in there. You might just need to play with it to see if you can find anything wrong. If you still have no luck, then you might just have to go buy a new head.